# C#: Find object names in file path for grouping?

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have multiple file paths, they are not all the same, but all contain a folder with the name of an object before diving further into the path at some point. The point isn't always consistent, and neither is the name. However, for the same objects, the object name will remain consistent across multiple paths. For example:

1. C:\abc\i33\p4l\object1\so1\mko0\blah\filename.ext
2. C:\abc\i33\p4l\object1\so1\jiop1\mei\filename.ext
3. C:\abc\i33\p4l\object1\so1\jum\i99\filename.ext

In the above example, the name I am looking for is 'object1'. However, in this next example, I am looking for 'pkwm34'.

1. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\pkwm34\werg\asdc\ddf\filename.ext
2. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf\filename.ext
3. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf\filename.ext
4. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf4\filename.ext
5. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf4\filename.ext
6. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\ji2345op1\sdfg\filename.ext
7. C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\juxcm\isdf99\filename.ext

I am completely unsure of how to approach this issue since KMP algorithm still requires the complete string, plus a pattern to search for. So essentially the way I'm analyzing it, I would have to find all exact pattern matches which could be broken out using string.Split, but then in a real world scenario I'm ending up with a split on '\' and '_' then ending up with a good 50+ patterns to search for. This has been a difficult task and I would love some help on it at this point. Another issue that could arise, or that someone might ask about would be the fact that none of the patterns are going to be in a recognizable language. Also, I have no access to external tools in this case due to work restrictions.

***EDIT***

In order to assist all that come to answer this question I will be posting  answers to questions in comments that are useful so that you can find them quickly at the bottom of this post.

- The folder name delimiter is not always an underscore, it can be a space as well.
- The folder name is not at a consistent level of hierarchy, it can be anywhere from second level to last level.
- The fastest implementation is not necessary, brute force algorithms can be used.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: But it's always at the 4th level of the directory hyrarchy? Or could it also be `C:\abc\i33\p4l\FOO\object1\mko0\blah\filename.ext`? (foo is now at 4th level and object1 at 5th). Is the underline always the delimiter of the folder-name?

Comment: No, yes, and not sure what you mean. I've been searching for consistency throughout for the previous few weeks and nothing so far aside from the object name. It can be second, third, all the way to 9th level deep in the hierarchy. As far as the delimiter, I'm seeing spaces, underscores, and dashes, although the dashes appear to be part of another naming convention.

Comment: Fast and easy wouldn't be a requirement, it could run in the background at startup while other components are loading, this isn't an issue.

Comment: Are the names you're searching to group by known in advance? If not, why in the first example do I pick "object1" instead of "abc", "i33", "p4l", or on the other end "so1"?

Comment: I don't think there really are any indications. I think I may have found an algorithm that could help. It's Levinshtein's distance formula which could be used for fuzzy logic, and then compare the fuzzy results to get accurate results.

Comment: that's usually pretty good for comparing two strings, but in this case it looks more like you're trying to match a name to a substring of a string. The areas outside of your substring are going to make the results very noisy and not sure if it will give you the results back you're looking for. I haven't tested the two below, but replacing textToFind's options in kots with your own known names or replacing lookingfor's value in Tim's with a passed in property and foreaching over your object_name list/array may be a safe bet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation using RegEx pattern search:

```
        var list = new List<string>
        {
            @"C:\abc\i33\p4l\object1\so1\mko0\blah\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\abc\i33\p4l\object1\so1\jiop1\mei\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\abc\i33\p4l\object1\so1\jum\i99\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\pkwm34\werg\asdc\ddf\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf4\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\werg\asdc\ddf4\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\ji2345op1\sdfg\filename.ext ",
            @"C:\ertgh\xcvh\bfrth32456\abc_pkwm34_abc_abc_jj5\juxcm\isdf99\filename.ext "
        };
        var textToFind = @"\W*(object1)|(pkwm34)\W*";
        var results = list.Where(x =>
            x.Split('\\').Any(y => Regex.IsMatch(y, textToFind, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: This requires knowing the text to search for before searching for it.